Why am i not able to scroll my cards horizontally when i add smoothscroll.js?
I have a component which generates card in a single line using flex. before i applied smooth scroll to all my project, the horizontal scroll on the cards was working fine. but as soon as i added smoothscroll, the horizontal scroll stopped working.
Dashboard.jsx
        <Layout>
            <div className="pt-32 pb-6">
                <h1 className="flex justify-center font-bebas font-semibold text-8xl text-indigo-500 tracking-wide">
                    BUSINESS DASHBOARD.
                </h1>
            </div>              

            <div className="flex flex-col space-y-12 py-16">
                <div className="flex border-indigo-500 border-x-2 mx-12 py-1 pl-6 overflow-x-auto">
                    <div className="flex flex-nowrap space-x-6">
                        {appointments.map((appointment) => (
                            <div key={appointment._id} className="flex-shrink-0">
                                <AppointmentCard
                                    appointment={appointment}
                                    businessName={appointment.businessName}
                                    serviceName={appointment.service.title}
                                />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Layout>

Layout.jsx
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Navbar from "./navbar/Navbar";
import BacktoTopButton from "./BacktoTopButton";
import SmoothScroll from "./SmoothScroll";

function Layout({ children }) {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
            <SmoothScroll />
            <Navbar />
            <div
                className="pattern-topography-darkieGreen/10 pattern-topography-scale-[0.5] flex-grow bg-[#FAF8ED] bg-center bg-fixed scroll-container"
                // style={{ backgroundImage: "url('./images/parallax5.webp')" }}
            >
                {children}
            </div>
            <BacktoTopButton />
        </div>
    );
}

Layout.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default Layout;

SmoothScroll.jsx
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Scrollbar from "smooth-scrollbar";
import OverscrollPlugin from "smooth-scrollbar/plugins/overscroll";

function SmoothScroll() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const options = {
            damping: 0.15,
            renderByPixels: true,
            alwaysShowTracks: false,
            continuousScrolling: true,
            plugins: {
                overscroll: {
                    enable: true,
                    effect: "bounce",
                    damping: 0.2,
                    maxOverscroll: 30,
                },
            },
        };

        Scrollbar.use(OverscrollPlugin);
        const scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(
            document.querySelector(".scroll-container"),
            options
        );

        return () => {
            if (scrollbar) scrollbar.destroy();
        };
    }, []);

    return null;
}

export default SmoothScroll;

The smooth scroll is working fine by the way. Its just the horizontal scroll on the cards thats the issue.
